# Please enumerate all kinds of comprehensions in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, set-comprehension

So far, I've learned about

- list
- set
- dictionary
- generator

comprehensions. Are there any other iterables that can be ''comprehended''? I'm mostly interested in Python 3.

Comment: Note, however, that a generator is not a comprehension, despite the similarity in syntax.

Comment: I know that, but you can write a generator as a comprehension, cf. https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201605/generator_comprehensions.html

Answer (score 0):

```
my_dict = {i:char for i,char in enumerate("Hello, world!")}
my_list = [i**2 for i in range(10)]
my_set = {i**2 for i in range(10)}
my_generator = (i**2 for i in range(10))
```

In terms of just comprehensions, there aren't any more that I'm aware of. You could of course use a list/generator comprehension within (say) a tuple constructor to create a (in this case) tuple. But that's not a generator per se

Comment: I know how these work. My question is if there are other comprehensions than the ones mentioned.